# What is the difference between Export as PDF and Export > Format: PDF (Preview)

Tags: pdf, preview, drawing

Recently I drew a simple line on a blank page in Preview. I realized, that if I export the Document via File > Export as PDF, and open the exported Document, I don't have the ability to move around and edit the line.
If I alternatively use File > Export and then choose 'Format: PDF' I can edit the exported file later.
So this lead me to the question, why there are 2 different PDF Export 'Formats' in Preview. I believe that this might pose a slight security risk, since editable PDF Documents can later be manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, PDFs can always be edited, and if you used a decent vector artwork editor *(of which Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Inkscape, and Picta Inc.'s Graphic are examples, and Preview is not)*, you would be able to move the line from either export method. There is no 'security' to be had.

There are certainly differences between the two types of PDF Export. **File > Export As PDF** will place your image onto the default paper size. This is most noticeable if you have an image that's not A4 or US Letter. **File > Export > Format: PDF** will keep the dimensions of the image.

The former type of Export keeps the line data as an annotation, whereas the latter type of export flattens the data as just a 'line' within the PDF.

As to why Preview has such as clumsy interface: only an Apple insider can tell you that. There are many mysteries about why Preview is such a terrible showcase for the brilliant Quartz graphics APIs that lie beneath, and we may never know.